# move boot partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.10

I want extend my root and home partitions. Is it safe to move the boot partition (the green one, to the right of the anallocated space) to the left?

I'm doing it from live USB with Gparted, and yes, I do have backups, but nevertheless better ask before..
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Most desktops do not need separate /boot. And now Ubuntu uses swap file, although many still suggest swap partition. I have removed /boot (years ago) by copying everything into /boot folder & removing /boot partition & entry in fstab. Similar to reverse of moving /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  You probably need to swapoff or unmount swap. Click on it in gparted to change. Little key  icon says mounted.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to keep things as it is but if you want to do it give it a try, as you said you have the backup

Answer (score 1):

No, it will surely end up crashing up the OS as there are immovable system files at the very end of the volume and disturbing these will disrupt it all.